# How can you keep the Structure window always displayed in Android Studio 3.5.1?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm sure that I open the Structure window in my `Android Studio 3.5.1` project, you can see *Image 1*, but sometimes `Android Studio 3.5.1` hide the Structure window automatically.

I hope to keep the Structure window displayed. How can I do?

**Image 1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-modes.html#docked) you just need to choose `Dock Pinned` as View Mode of the Tool Window:

> You can make a tool window stay open even if your focus is somewhere else, for example, in the editor or other tool window. To achieve that, use the Dock pinned mode when you select your viewing mode.

Here are the [steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-modes.html#ways-to-control) to change it:

> On the title bar of a tool window, click the Show Options Menu icon, from the list of options, select View Mode and the actual mode option.

[image: View Mode]

> Right-click a tool window or a title bar and from the list of options, select View Mode and the actual mode option.

[image: Dock Pinned]

Comment: Thanks! I have set View Mode as Dock Pinned. But sometimes Android Studio 3.5.1 Still hide the Structure window automatically, such as I open another Project.